Differential equation for a heavy rope getting pulled upwards
Suppose there's a non-stretchable rope sitting on a flat surface with total mass $M$ and length $L$. You pull one end upward with a constant force $F$. The part above the surface has mass $m$ and length $l$. Ignore thickness and friction. What is the differential equation that describes $l(t)$?

Original question:
"A uniform 10-foot-long heavy rope is coiled loosely on the ground. As shown in FIGURE 1.R.2 one end of the rope is pulled vertically upward by means of a constant force of $5$ lb. The rope weighs $1$ lb/ft. Use Newton's second law in the form given in (17) in Exercises 1.3 to determine a differential equation for the height $x(t)$ of the end above ground level at time $t$. Assume that the positive direction is upward"

Attempt
Newton's Second Law states that $F_{net}=\frac{d}{dt}[mv]$. The net force acting on the upper part (part above the surface) is $F_{net}=F - mg$ where we take the positive direction to be upward. The RHS becomes $\frac{dm}{dt} v + m\frac{dv}{dt}$. Assuming the rope has a constant density, $m=\frac{M}{L}l$.
$F - mg = \frac{dm}{dt} v + m\frac{dv}{dt}$
$F - mg = (\frac{M}{L}\frac{dl}{dt}) (\frac{1}{2}\frac{dl}{dt}) + (\frac{M}{L}l)(\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2l}{dt^2})$
$\frac{M}{2L}(\frac{dl}{dt})^2+\frac{Ml}{2L}\frac{d^2l}{dt^2}+mg-F=0$
The reason why there's a $\frac{1}{2}$ is because the motion is of the center of mass; since $x_{CM} = \frac{l}{2}$, $v_{CM} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{dl}{dt}$ and $a_{CM} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2l}{dt^2}$. The textbook seems to agree with my final equation but not about the $\frac{1}{2}$. I tried searching things up but it just seems to skip the fact that the center of mass and therefore its motion is half the length $l$. Am I wrong about something? Is it special that it is a rope? Is the textbook wrong?
Text: Advanced Engineering Mathematics 6th ed., Dennis G. Zill, Chapter 1 "Chapter in Review" problem 43

Why are you using the center of mass? My approach was to treat the ropes top as an object of increasing mass, who's mass increases as m = rho y

@jensenpaull The center of mass must be used because the velocity in Newton's second law is about the center of mass, not necessarily the change of length of the top.

Do you agree that a point particle moving upwards accelerated by a constant driving force with an increasing mass in the form m= rho y  is identical to the situation you pose? (Plus of minus specific technicalities we want to ignore)

@jensenpaull Yes, with the "technicalities" being rho = M/L, y = l/2

By y I mean the coordinate you choose as l, so m=M/L l (exactly what you wrote)

I see. Therefore, if we can consider the upper part of the rope as a particle with all its mass concentrated on the top, the textbook solution must be correct. But why not any other point? Why not set y as the bottom or the center?

Because when y is a certain value, by defining m=rho y  we are assuming it is the top, as from 0 to y, carries mass. If we pick a different point y to be e.g 1m down the end of the rope,  we aren't including the mass above the point, so as a model the only logical conclusion is that y is the top of the rope. Just from the point particle analogy, as the rope reaches a height of y it has an apparent mass rho y
